# How to setup Oracle Instant Client with XAMPP in macOS Mojave?

Tags: php, oracle, terminal, xampp

I am using macOS and have successfully installed and set up XAMPP on my system. But the problem is that I want to connect to an oracle database through PHP Easy Syntax like below:

```
$conn = oci_connect('xx', 'xx', '123.123.xxx.x/xxxx');
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

But i get this error on running the page

```
Call to undefined function oci_connect()
```

After reading some article i found that i have to install oracle instant client but i really don't know the steps to download which version and then where to unzip the files in xampp folder. I am really a novice in this area.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did on macOS Mojave.  I used the native installer XAMPP 7.4.9 from
xampp-osx-7.4.9-0-installer.dmg.  I did a basic install with the Developer files
option selected - this was the default.

It seems like XAMPP for macOS doesn't have the OCI8 extension built.  (I noticed
the XAMPP VM install from xampp-osx-7.4.9-0-vm.dmg also didn't have the OCI8
extension, but I haven't played with it yet.)

Sadly the 'obvious' method of installing OCI8 with the `pecl` command fails to
correctly find the right PHP version.  E.g. running:

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/pecl install oci8
```

and answering:

```
instantclient,/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/instantclient-11.2.0.3.0/
```

fails with `checking PHP version... Unknown option: n`.  The PECL config looked OK, but there must have been some conflict with the native PHP version.

Anyway, the slightly longer manual install of OCI8 works.  The instructions are below.

- I prefer to use a more recent Instant Client, so download the latest Instant
  Client Basic and SDK packages from
  [here](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/macos-intel-x86-downloads.html)
  and unzip them:

  ```
  cd $HOME/Downloads
  curl -O https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/mac/instantclient/instantclient-basic-macos.zip
  curl -O https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/mac/instantclient/instantclient-sdk-macos.zip
  ```
- Extract the Instant Client (substitute your download directory path):

  ```
  cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib
  sudo unzip /Users/cjones/Downloads/instantclient-basic-macos.zip
  sudo unzip /Users/cjones/Downloads/instantclient-sdk-macos.zip
  ```
- You can optionally do some cleanup.  Get rid of the old Instant Client:

  ```
  sudo rm -rf /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/instantclient-11.2.0.3.0
  ```

  and remove new libraries not needed by OCI8:

  ```
  sudo rm -f /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/instantclient_19_3/{*jdbc*,*occi*,*mysql*,*jar,uidrvci,genezi,adrci}
  ```
- Download the OCI8 extension from [PECL](https://pecl.php.net/package/oci8) and
  extract it:

  ```
  cd $HOME/Downloads
  curl -O https://pecl.php.net/get/oci8-2.2.0.tgz
  tar -xzf oci8-2.2.0.tgz
  ```
- Build and install OCI8.  You'll need some kind of compiler available; I have XCode installed:

  ```
  cd oci8-2.2.0
  /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/phpize
  ./configure --with-php-config=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php-config --with-oci8=shared,instantclient,/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/instantclient_19_3
  make
  sudo make install
  ```
- Then, tell XAMPP to enable the extension:

  ```
  sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp oci8
  ```

  At the prompt, enter the path to the Instant Client directory `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/instantclient_19_3` like:

  ```
  Please enter the path to your Oracle or Instant Client installation:
  [/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/instantclient-11.2.0.3.0] /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/instantclient_19_3
  installing symlink...
  patching php.ini...
  OCI8 add-on activation likely successful.
  XAMPP: Stopping Apache...ok.
  XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.
  ```
- Now when you check http://localhost/dashboard/phpinfo.php you should see the OCI8 section.

You may be interested in how to 'run' an Oracle DB on macOS, which can be done in a VirtualBox VM like: https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/the-easiest-way-to-install-oracle-database-on-apple-mac-os-x. Other people use a Docker container for the same thing.